# Displaying images using Picasso isn't working

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage, picasso

I tried to display image from Firebase Storage. So, I uploaded images into firebase storage and save a link into firebase realtime database. And when I tried to retrieve it using Picasso Library(v 2.71828) it isn't working but according to code, the task is getting successful everytime. Looking back into Firebase Storage, the picture uploaded successfully and the link of the image was successfully stored into firebase realtime database.

I tried the same code with Glide Library, but got the same problem.

Expected: Displaying Image using Picasso
Got: No error and No image displaying

```
private void retrieveUserInfo() 
{
    rootRef
    .child("Users").child(currentUserID)
    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
  {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
    {
        // if the user has created his profile then
        if((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name") && (dataSnapshot.hasChild(("image")))))
        {
            String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            String retrieveUserStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
            String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

            userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
            userStatus.setText(retrieveUserStatus);
            // using picasso library we will display the profile image
            Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);


        }

        // if the user don't wanna display image
        else if((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name")))
        {
            String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            String retrieveUserStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

            userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
            userStatus.setText(retrieveUserStatus);
        }
        else
        {
            //userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Please set and update your profile information...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) 
    {

    }
});
```

}

Comment: Please check your URL in the browser whether it's working

Comment: Can you provide what type of data your getting from db and Please Log `retrieveProfileImage`. For understanding firebase storage url token expire after certain amount of time so better store the location of File.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your internet permission granted?

You should have this in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yes I do. Manifests is okay with permissions. and everyting in firebase except the displaying retrieved image from firebase database

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not receiving the URL correctly from the Realtime Database.
I would try to print the URL first instead to make sure you're receiving it correctly.